# SQL JOIN ON Issues

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use a JOIN ON statement to `SELECT` two columns, one with the `Team_Name` and the other with how many times they have won. I want to include all teams, even those who haven't won at all.

This is the JOIN statement that I've been using but it only returns the `Team_Name` `Poki` and a `WinningTimes` of `0` which is incorrect as they've won once

```
SELECT Team_Name, SUM(Winner) AS WinningTimes 
From Robot_Winner r JOIN Robot_Combat c
ON r.BattleNo = c.BattleNo;



Team_Name    WinningTimes
Poki         0
```

```
Create Table Robot_Combat
(
BattleNo VarChar(3) Not null,
Team_Number Int Not null,
Team_Name VarChar(8) Not null,
Bot_Name VarChar(8) Not null,
Primary Key (BattleNo, Bot_Name)
);

Create Table Robot_Winner
(
BattleNo VarChar(3) Not null,
Winner VarChar (10) Not null,
Primary Key (BattleNo),
Foreign Key (BattleNo) References Robot_Combat(BattleNo)
);
```

This is the data inside each table

```
Robot_Combat
BattleNo [PK]   Team_Number Team_Name   Bot_Name
B07             1           A1          S1
B07             2           Poki        Pika
B08             1           Phenix      Kka
B08             2           StarWar     R2
B11             1           APT         4869
B11             2           Phenix      RedWin
B12             1           T1          E1
B12             2           S3          Sam5

Insert Into Robot_Combat (BattleNo, Team_Number, Team_Name, BotName)
Values ('B07', 1, 'A1', 'S1');
Insert Into Robot_Combat (BattleNo, Team_Number, Team_Name, BotName)
Values ('B07', 2, 'Poki', 'Pika');
Insert Into Robot_Combat (BattleNo, Team_Number, Team_Name, BotName)
Values ('B08', 1, 'Phenix', 'Kka');
Insert Into Robot_Combat (BattleNo, Team_Number, Team_Name, BotName)
Values ('B08', 2, 'StarWar', 'R2');
Insert Into Robot_Combat (BattleNo, Team_Number, Team_Name, BotName)
Values ('B11', 1, 'APT', '4869');
Insert Into Robot_Combat (BattleNo, Team_Number, Team_Name, BotName)
Values ('B11', 2, 'Phenix', 'RedWin');
Insert Into Robot_Combat (BattleNo, Team_Number, Team_Name, BotName)
Values ('B12', 1, 'T1', 'E1');
Insert Into Robot_Combat (BattleNo, Team_Number, Team_Name, BotName)
Values ('B12', 2, 'S3', 'Sam5');
```

```
Robot_Winner
BattleNo [FK][PK]   Winner
B07                 Poki
B08                 Phenix
B11                 Phenix
B12                 S3

Insert Into Robot_Winner(BattleNo, Winner)
Values ('B07','Poki);
Insert Into Robot_Winner(BattleNo, Winner)
Values ('B08','Phenix);
Insert Into Robot_Winner(BattleNo, Winner)
Values ('B11','Phenix);
Insert Into Robot_Winner(BattleNo, Winner)
Values ('B12','S3);
```

Comment: When sharing a sample data first check from your side then share.Like the alias name `s` and the `Winner VarChar (3)`

Comment: Tip: Keep in mind when sharing `create...` share `Insert..` statements too so that community can use to replicate in local faster. It would be kind if you add fiddle sample [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7)

Comment: If you need all records from one of joined tables you must use outer joining or correlated subquery. Simple join, which is INNER, cannot solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need Team Name and Winning count why you need a join instead you can get the `count` in the `Robot_Winner` right?

There you have the winning team name which is `Team_Name` and no of games won can be counted by grouping `Winner`.

So it can be written as below

```
select 
    Winner as Team_Name,
    count(*) as WinningTimes 
from 
    robot_winner
group by 
    Winner;
```

**Edit:**

Since you need all the teams and the no. of count won. You can use `left join` and select the team_name from `robot_combat` table.

```
select
    team.Team_Name as Team_Name,
    count(winner.Winner) as WinningTimes
from
    (select distinct Team_Name from robot_combat) as team
    left join robot_winner as winner on team.Team_Name = winner.Winner
group by 
    Team_Name;
```

**caveat:** You need to normalize your table like having a team names in a separate table.

Comment: Because I need to include the teams that didn't win.

Comment: Then you need to explain a bit in detail. So edit your question please